# Set baseURL in Artifactory via REST API

Tags: docker, artifactory

I am installing Artifactory using this docker image `docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:5.4.6` in kubernetes and then configuring an existing load balancer to point to it over https only.

When I curl to artifactory it redirects the https url to http:

```
< HTTP/2 302
< date: Tue, 05 Dec 2017 22:42:37 GMT
< content-length: 0
< location: http://dev-artifactory.lark.com/artifactory/webapp/
```

According to https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-UpdateCustomURLBase I should be able to issue a curl command to change that base url. However when I try this, which is basically copied from the docs:

```
curl -v -X PUT "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/system/configuration/baseUrl" \
  -d 'https://dev-artifactory.lark.com/artifactory' \
  -uadmin:XXX -H "Content-type: text/plain"
```

I get a `400` back but no error message:

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

How can I change this base url? Ideally I could set an ENV var. If I can't figure this out I guess I'll have to add the header `X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url` as described at https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Artifactory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact command (adding the password) you posted works fine on the exact container version you mentioned. Are you trying to run this command as Artifactory is still starting up?

In any case, even if it worked, the better approach is to use the `X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url`. This allows you to have potentially multiple different names for the Artifactory instance and avoids having to change any Artifactory configuration.

Comment: It must have been starting up like you said: now when I run it, it says it works. In the meantime, I also configured nginx to have `proxy_set_header    X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url https://dev-artifactory.lark.com/artifactory;` however when I run `curl -v https://dev-artifactory.lark.com/artifactory -L`, I continue to get the same `302` error trying to redirect to `http://...` instead of `https://...`. Any ideas why that would be?

Comment: That is a separate issue. It involves the redirects that happen at the NGINX level. You should be able to work around that by either removing these two lines: `rewrite ^/$ /artifactory/webapp/ redirect;`
`rewrite ^/artifactory/?(/webapp)?$ /artifactory/webapp/ redirect;`

Or hardcoding them like this:

`rewrite ^/$ https://dev-artifactory.lark.com/artifactory/webapp/ redirect;`
`rewrite ^/artifactory/?(/webapp)?$ https://dev-artifactory.lark.com/artifactory/webapp/ redirect;`